# How to match a pattern given in a variable in awk?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, substring

I want to extract a substring where certain pattern exist from pipe separated file, thus I used below command,

```
awk -F ":" '/REWARD REQ. SERVER HEADERS/{print $1, $2, $3, $4}' sample_profile.txt
```

Here, 'REWARD REQ. SERVER HEADERS' is a pattern which is to be searched in the file, and print its first 4 parts on a colon separated line.

Now, I want to send bash variable to act as a pattern. thus I used below command, but it's not working.

```
awk -v pat="$pattern" -F ":" '/pat/{print $1, $2 , $3, $4 } sample_profile.txt
```

How can I use `-v` and `-F` in a single `awk` command?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

If you want to provide the pattern through a variable, you need to use `~` to match against it:

```
awk -v pat="$pattern" '$0 ~ pat'
```

---

In your case, the problem does not have to do with `-F`.

The problem is the usage of `/pat/` when you want `pat` to be a variable. If you say `/pat/`, `awk` understands it as a literal "pat", so it will try to match those lines containing the string "pat".

All together, your code should be:

```
awk -v pat="$pattern" -F ":" '$0~pat{print $1, $2, $3, $4 }' file
#                             ^^^^^^
```

---

See an example:

Given this file:

```
$ cat file
hello
this is a var
hello bye
```

Let's look for lines containing "hello":

```
$ awk '/hello/' file
hello
hello bye
```

Let's now try looking for "pat", contained in a variable, the way you were doing it:

```
$ awk -v pat="hello" '/pat/' file
$                                    # NO MATCHES!
```

Let's now use the `$0 ~ pat` expression:

```
$ awk -v pat="hello" '$0~pat' file
hello                                 # WE MATCH!
hello bye
```

---

Of course, you can use such expressions to match just one field and say `awk -v pat="$pattern" '$2 ~ pat' file` and so on.

From [GNU Awk User's Guide → 3.1 How to Use Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp-Usage):

> When a regexp is enclosed in slashes, such as /foo/, we call it a regexp constant, much like 5.27 is a numeric constant and "foo" is a string constant.

And [GNU Awk User's Guide → 3.6 Using Dynamic Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps):

> The righthand side of a ‘~’ or ‘!~’ operator need not be a regexp
> constant (i.e., a string of characters between slashes). It may be any
> expression. The expression is evaluated and converted to a string if
> necessary; the contents of the string are then used as the regexp. A
> regexp computed in this way is called a dynamic regexp or a computed
> regexp:
>
> ```
> BEGIN { digits_regexp = "[[:digit:]]+" }
> $0 ~ digits_regexp    { print }
> ```
>
> This sets digits_regexp to a regexp that describes one or more digits,
> and tests whether the input record matches this regexp.

Comment: What about mixing a variable with text constants like "text${var}othertext" as pattern?

Comment: @BlackEye just use it normally: `awk -v pat="text${v}othertext" '$0 ~ pat' file`.

Comment: How can we use this when we later need access to matching sub-patterns? That is, in my `awk` script, I have `match($0, /^(Foo)(Bar)$/, m)` (that is, in case of match `m[1]` contains `Foo` and `m[2]` contains `Bar`), and I now would need something like `match($0, /^(Foo${Var})(Bar)$/, m)` (so that in case of match e.g. `m[1]` becomes `FooBoo` when `Var` is `Boo`). Does the `match` function only support constant patterns?

Comment: @Binarus frankly, I don't know right now. I suggest asking a new question, since this may be of interest to many.

Comment: Actually, it's in the manual, but I was hoping for a more elegant and faster method. Since a variable's content can be embedded in a string, we can construct the pattern in string form and give that string to the `match()` function (instead of a real pattern). The manual states that this will cost performance (because the string must be scanned twice); furthermore, it is cumbersome (e.g. because ```\``` must be written as ```\\``` in the string). Apart from that, it works as expected.

Comment: ...and in case anyone's wondering how to make it PART of a pattern, here's an example:`$0 ~ /^."$myvar"/    { }`

Answer (score 13):

```
awk -v pat="$pattern" -F":" '$0 ~ pat { print $1, $2, $3, $4 }' sample_profile.txt
```

You can't use the variable inside the regex `//` notation (there's no way to distinguish it from searching for `pat`); you have to specify that the variable is a regex with the `~` (matching) operator.

Comment: The `{print $1, $2, $3, $4}` portion really helps me to realise that I can also print a specific column only. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand why no answer mentions the most obvious solution: **using double quotes**.

**BEWARE** that this poses a risk of code injection ([demonstration (see "Variable within the code")](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19075707)), but this solution works for some syntaxes where @fedorqui's answer falls short.

#### Simple Pattern (alone)

Simply doing this:

```bash
awk "/$mybashvar/"
```

will work.

#### Range Pattern (alone)

And this will even work for [**range patterns**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Ranges) while @fedorqui 's solution will not.

Consider I want to match all the lines between `"start #${myid}"` and `"end"`, we can do this like so:

```bash
awk "/start #${myid}/,/end/"
```

#### Full Awk Script

Now, using double quotes breaks some `awk` functionality (like awk variable for instance because they'll be evaluated by the shell now, especially field variables like `$1`), and it's much safer to use single quotes for complicated `awk` script (to prevent shell interpreation of anything). But you can still go around this like so:

```bash
awk '/'"$mypattern"'/ {print $1}'
```

Basically you still use double quotes around the bash variable but single quote everywhere else and concatenate it all to get your full `awk` script.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a hack but it makes things a little simpler for me.

```
cmd="awk '/$pattern/'"
eval $cmd
```

making it a string first lets you manipulate it past the boundaries of awk

Comment: Careful using `eval` ... you could be doing something like `pattern="/';rm -rf /;echo '` if you don't sanitize `$pattern`

Comment: A better way would be to just use double quotes instead: `awk "/$pattern/"`