# How to grep the first occurrence of a word after a pattern

Tags: search, grep

I have an output of an analysis and I would like to grep a keyword "X" -which always appears- every time a phrase "Y" occurs. The keyword "X" appears many times but I would like to get only the subsequent after "Y".

For example, I would like to get the subsequent Folder name every time Iter = 10 occurs, i.e. F1, F4.

```
Iter   = 10
Folder = F1

Iter   = 5
Folder = F2

Iter   = 6
Folder = F3

Iter   = 10
Folder = F4
```

Any ideas?

Hexdump -c output of file (as requested by @Inian):

```
0000000   I   t   e   r               =       1   0  \n   F   o   l   d
0000010   e   r       =       F   1  \n  \n   I   t   e   r            
0000020   =       5  \n   F   o   l   d   e   r       =       F   2  \n
0000030  \n   I   t   e   r               =       6  \n   F   o   l   d
0000040   e   r       =       F   3  \n  \n   I   t   e   r            
0000050   =       1   0  \n   F   o   l   d   e   r       =       F   4
0000060  \n                                                            
0000061
```

Comment: So you made any efforts for yourself? Has it needs to be with `grep`? Can `Awk` be used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `awk` for this requirement. It works on a `/pattern/{action}` based rule on each line of the input file. So in our case we first match the string `Iter   = 10` and enable a flag so that on the next match of the string starting with `Folder`, we extract the last space de-limited column, which in `awk` is represented by `$NF` and we reset the flag for subsequent matches.

```
awk '/\<Iter   = 10\>/{flag=1; next} flag && /^Folder/{print $NF; flag=0;}' file
```

or without the `<>` try

```
awk '/Iter   = 10/{flag=1; next} flag && /^Folder/{print $NF; flag=0;}' file
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved it, now it works. Can you explain the difference?

Comment: @alex: That is used to match the entire pattern, meaning that there cannot be any more characters other than `Iter = 10` in that line

Comment: How do I modify this when I need to search using a variable ? I tried something like var="Iter=10" ; awk -v var_name="$var" '/var_name/{flag=1; next} flag && /^Folder/{print $NF; flag=0;}' file . This doesnt work for me

Comment: @spooja__: See [How to match a pattern given in a variable in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39384283/5291015)

Comment: @Inian Thanks ! I went through it more carefully and  I think I could figure it out now . This worked for me : var2=`awk -v var_name="$var" '$0~var_name file {flag=1; next} flag && /^Folder/{print $NF; flag=0;}' file`

Answer (score 2):

You could also you `grep`:

```
$ grep -A 1 Iter.*10 file | grep Folder | grep -o "[^ ]*$"
F1
F4
```

Explained:

- `grep -A 1 Iter.*10 file` search for desired pattern and get some trailing context (`-A 1`, just one line)
- `grep Folder` next search for keyword `Folder`
- `grep -o "[^ ]*$"` get the last part of previous output

If there is noise between `Iter` and `Folder` lines you could remove that with `grep "\(Iter.*10\|Folder\)" file` first.

Above expects for `Iter` line to appear before `Folder` line. If that is not the case, awk is the cure. For example, data (line orders vary, there is noise):

```
Folder = F1
Foo    = bar
Iter   = 10

Iter   = 5
Foo    = bar
Folder = F2

$ awk -v RS="" -F"\n" '                        # record separated by empty line
/Iter/ && / 10$/ {                             # look for record with Iter 10
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                         # iterate all fields (lines within record)
        if(split($i,a," *") && a[1]=="Folder") # split Folder line to components
            print a[3]                         # output value
}
' file
F1
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep a note for this. There is noise, so awk is the cure as Inian mentioned. Works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is simply regrex search.

For, doing more complex operation, you can use `awk`.

E.g.

```
awk '/Iter = 10/ { getline; print $0 }' /path/to/file
```

where /path/to/file is the file containing your text to be searched

EDIT:
Just after posting my answer I read Inian's answer and it is more elaborate and accurate.

Comment: This is just to get the next line, I need it to search on file after the occurrence of 'Iter  = 10' for Folder, where Folder can be anywhere.

Comment: yes. as I mentioned, Inian's answer is more elaborate. I just showed an example way to do it.