# (awk?) match between shell variable and string

Tags: regex, awk

I have a file like this (where xxxxn = any random string):

```
xxxx1
xxxx2
xxxx3
xxxx4
END
xxxx5
xxxx6
xxxx7
END
xxxx8
...
```

I want to match between a shell variable and the next END.
Say the shell variable equals xxxx2, I would like:

```
xxxx3
xxxx4
```

I think awk is probably the tool for the job but I'm open to other commands.

I have got it working if I hard code it (with xxxx2 again) like so:

```
awk '/xxxx2/{flag=1;next}/^END/{flag=0}flag' file
```

But I would like it to reference a shell variable and the symbols to be escaped.
I tried:

```
awk -v var="$my_var" '/~var/{flag=1;next}/^END/{flag=0}flag' file
```

(After reading this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39384347/11633601)
But that outputs nothing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Var should be declared with -v for `awk` [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

So this should do:

```
my_var="xxxx2"
awk -v var="$my_var" '/END/ {exit} f; $0==var {f=1}' file
xxxx3
xxxx4
```

You could set `f=0` to stop printing, but `exit` is better since it stops processing data.

```
awk -v var="$my_var" '/END/ {f=0} f; $0==var {f=1}' file
```

Comment: I suggest to replace `f=1` with `f=1; next` to remove  `xxxx2` from output.

Comment: @Cyrus Did forget that `xxxx2` should not be printed.  Its better to  swap around test, compare to use `next`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the hard-coded `xxxx2` with the shell variable, but outside of the single quotes, and double it in case it contains white spaces:

```
awk /"$my_var"'/{flag=1;next}/^END$/{flag=0}flag' file
```

Also, you should consider using the `ed` command instead as pointed out by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/472053) so it would be much more readable:

```
echo /"$my_var"'/+1,/^END$/-1p' | ed -s file -
```

Comment: Lets say line 2 in OPs post is `\xxxx2`.  Then you set `my_var="\xxxx2"`.  Then you code will fail due to your way to use variable in `awk`.  You could also put code in your variable and make it execute in your `awk` code. (code injection)