# How to print everything between two patterns using awk

Tags: awk

I can print everything between two patterns with this awk command:

```
awk '/'$1'/{a=1} a; /PATTERN2/{a=0}' ~/the/path/to/file.txt
```

What I need is to print everything between and include **PATTERN1** and everything before **PATTERN2** (which is always a line that starts with `#`.

Actually the patterns are hashtags like `#france` and `#germany`.

For example the file contains:

```
#france
France is a European country.
It's capital city is Paris.
One of its biggest cities is Lyon.

#germany
Germany is a European country.
It's capital city is Berlin.
One of its biggest cities is Munich.
```

What I want to be printed after calling **#france**:

```
#france
France is a European country.
It's capital city is Paris.
One of its biggest cities is Lyon.
```

Also it would be great if I can show the pattern in another color like blue or red.

Comment: Btw.: [How to match a pattern given in a variable in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39384283/3776858)

Comment: Please read [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) and [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pattern of setting a flag based on matching the section you want to print:

```
awk -v cc="#france" '/^#/{f=($1==cc)} f' file
#france
France is a European country.
It's capital city is Paris.
One of its biggest cities is Lyon.
```

Or:

```
awk -v cc="#germany" '/^#/{f=($1==cc)} f' file
#germany
Germany is a European country.
It's capital city is Berlin.
One of its biggest cities is Munich.
```

This will never start printing if there is not a match, and it only stops printing when another `#hashtag` is encountered.

---

*How can I colorize the pattern?*

You would use [ANSI Escape Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) as in [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5947802/298607). This is dependent if your terminal setup supports ANSI codes. Most do.

Example:

```
awk -v cc="#germany" '/^#/{
    f=($1==cc)
    if (f) printf("\033[0;31m%s\033[0m\n", $0)
    next 
    } 
    f' file
```

Prints (on my terminal):

```
#germany                             # red on black
Germany is a European country.       # green on black...
It's capital city is Berlin.         # green is the default color
One of its biggest cities is Munich.
```

Comment: Thanks, It works well. How can I colorize the pattern? e.g: ```#france```

Comment: With ANSI codes. See edit

Answer (score 2):

If there is always blank line between entries you might harness paragraph mode of GNU `AWK` by setting `RS` to empty string, let `file.txt` content be

```
#france
France is a European country.
It's capital city is Paris.
One of its biggest cities is Lyon.

#germany
Germany is a European country.
It's capital city is Berlin.
One of its biggest cities is Munich.
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}/^#france/' file.txt
```

output

```
#france
France is a European country.
It's capital city is Paris.
One of its biggest cities is Lyon.
```

Explanation: `RS=""` causes GNU `AWK` to treat paragraphs as rows. I simply filter rows which starts with (`^`) `#france`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples only, you can try following `awk` code. Where I am using `RS`(record separator) as paragraph mode and checking if line starts from particular string then print that whole para.

```
awk -v RS="" '$0~/^#france\n/' Input_file
```